# Microsoft Graph API - determine delegated information using application (daemon) identity

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

Im working on getting mailFolders info with Microsoft Graph API(`/users/{id}/mailFolders`) using daemon application token. In this case I can receive folders for any users. But when authenticating as an application (as opposed to with a user), you can't use delegated permissions.

How using application identity check if user has access to the delegated folder or can MS Graph somehow enforce a user's access to another user's mailbox when using an application identity?

Comment: As you think, the daemon does not support delegated permissions. If you want to use delegated permissions, you should call the `/me` endpoint   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders`.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with Carl :)

Comment: Thanks! In my case I use only daemon identity and wanted to see if is possible for one user has access to the mailbox of another using the MS Graph API with Application token? I thought maybe is other MS Graph endpoints to see list of delegated user or something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's impossible.

Firstly you need to learn about [the difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/delegated-and-app-perms) between Application token (Application permission) and User token (Delegated Permission) in Azure AD.

> How using application identity check if user has access to the
> delegated folder？

When you use an application token, you are playing an application which has access to all the mailboxes. You are not signing in as a user, so you can't check the access permission of a user to another user's mailbox.

> Can MS Graph somehow enforce a user's access to another user's mailbox
> when using an application identity?

Similarly, this feature itself is not provided by MS Graph. You can [Use the EAC to assign permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/how-to-access-other-mailboxes#use-the-eac-to-assign-permissions) or [Assign permissions to the entire mailbox with Exchange Online Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/how-to-access-other-mailboxes#assign-permissions-to-the-entire-mailbox).

Comment: So there is no solution to determine if one user has access to the mailbox of another using the MS Graph API with Application token? I thought maybe is other MS Graph endpoints to see list of delegated user or something like this. Thanks

Comment: @YuraMo No. I'm afraid that there are no Graph endpoints showing this information.